# Keep listview item backcolor when row selected

Tags: vb.net

I have a listview control with several subitems. One of the subitem columns has a background color of red, orange or green depending on the record. When the row is selected i would like the colored subitem to retain its backcolor rather than being overwritten with the selection color. Is this possible?

Comment: Then how would you tell which item is selected? And by "you", I mean, "the user of your application".

Comment: WPF or WinForms ? In WPF you will have to modify the template of the item.

Comment: Its in vb.net winforms, and the other columns(subitems) would show the selection but this particular column would not.

Comment: I've done something similar in the past with a datagridview where i used;   dgvAr.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Style.SelectionBackColor = dgvAr.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Style.BackColor but cant get anything equivalent to work in a listview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `ListView1.OwnerDraw` to `True`.

Inside the ListView1's **Draw...** events:

```
Private Sub ListView1_DrawColumnHeader(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawColumnHeader
    e.DrawDefault = True ' let System draw this element
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawItem
    e.DrawDefault = True ' let System draw this element
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DrawSubItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawSubItem
    If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then ' only this columnindex we take over the drawing job
        e.DrawBackground() ' draw the background color
        e.DrawText()
    Else ' other subitems, let System draw them
        e.DrawDefault = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's long time ago, but this works while all my attempts at overriding OnMouseMove and OnItemMouseHover never got within an inch. Thanks for showing it can be done with a few lines of code wrt the drawing